# PHP: ¿necesitaría usar una expresión regular?

Tags: php, regex

He diseñado una función para extraer la localización de un grupo musical a partir de textos de esta forma (os pongo además los dos que me han dado el problema que intento solventar en este hilo):

"Fuel to burn", de Aerogramme (Glasgow, Escocia). Extraído de su EP "Glam cripple EP (Fukd I.D. #1)".

"You're pretty good looking (for a girl)", de The White Stripes (Detroit, EEUU). Extraído de su LP "De stijl".

La función es la siguiente:

```
  # 2.5. Localización: devuelve un array con dos componentes, ciudad ([0]) y país ([1])

  function localizacion($linea) 
  {
    $inicio = strpos($linea, " (");
    $final = strpos($linea, ").");
    $distancia = $final - $inicio;

    $localizacion = substr($linea, $inicio + 2, $distancia - 2);
    $localizacion_array = explode(",", $localizacion);

    return $localizacion_array;
  }
```

Bien, el problema es que esta función se lía con la canción de los White Stripes, porque encuentra el patrón " (" en el propio título; pensé que la solución sería usar `strrpos()` en vez de `strpos()`, pero entonces se lía con la de Aerogramme porque encuentra el patrón en el título del disco.

¿Se os ocurre algún otro patrón que podría usar o he de recurrir a una expresión regular -con las que apenas tengo experiencia-? De ser así, ¿cuál podría ser su sintaxis?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías aplicar la siguiente expresión regular: `([^)(]+),\s*([^)(]+)(?=\)\.\s*Extraído)`

Aplicado a una función, podría ser algo similar a esto:

```
function localizacion($linea) 
{
    $re = '/([^)(]+),\s*([^)(]+)\)\.\s*Extraído/m';
    preg_match_all($re, $linea, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    return(array($matches[0][1], $matches[0][2]));
}
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://www.ideone.com/CmUujG)

**Explicación**

La idea es capturar los paréntesis que hay antes de `. Extraído`

```
(             # Este paréntesis no es literal, sirve para 'capturar'
              # lo que tiene dentro. Es el primer grupo de captura
    [^)(]+    # Cualquier caracter salvo paréntesis izquierdo o derecho, una o más veces
)             # Fin del primer grupo de captura
,             # una coma, literal
\s*           # Cualquier tipo de espacio (espacio, tabulador...) cero o más veces
(             # Inicio del segundo grupo de captura
    [^)(]+    # Cualquier caracter salvo paréntesis izquierdo o derecho, una o más veces
)             # Fin del segundo grupo de captura
\)            # Paréntesis derecho (debe escaparse)
\.            # Un punto literal (debe escaparse)
\s*           # cero o más blancos
Extraído      # La palabra 'Extraído'
```

Finalmente en `matches` tendremos los grupos de captura, que devolveremos con

```
return(array($matches[0][1], $matches[0][2]));
```

Tienes más información en la página de php de [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias, parece funcionar perfectamente. Ahora sólo tengo que entender cómo lo hace, jajaja...

Comment: Gracias @Optigan. He editado la respuesta para simplificar un poco la expresión regular y añadirle la explicación. Saludos.

Comment: Genial, Julio, muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si solo deseas obtener la localización podrías usar una expresión regular como esta:

```
\(\w+,\s\w+\)
```

Comment: Es una mejora respecto a lo que tiene OP, pero fallará si el título de la canción tiene una coma dentro de paréntesis

Comment: no acaba de encajarme este regex, para empezar el paréntesis no está compensado.

Comment: lo he modificado, no me había dado cuenta de ello

Answer (score 0):

Me ha surgido un problema similar al intentar extraer el nombre del autor (en ese caso, el patrón de cierre a buscar es `$final = strpos($linea, " (");`, por lo que de nuevo se hace un lío cuando se lo encuentra primero en el título de la canción de los White Stripes) y lo he solucionado con una ñapa `$alarma` que sería aplicable a esta función también:

```
  function localizacion($linea) 
  {
    $inicio = strpos($linea, " (");
    $final = strpos($linea, ").");
    $alarma = strpos($linea, '", de ');

    if($inicio < $alarma) $inicio = strrpos($linea, " (");

    $distancia = $final - $inicio;

    $localizacion = substr($linea, $inicio + 2, $distancia - 2);
    $localizacion_array = explode(",", $localizacion);

    return $localizacion_array;
  }
```